# Highlighting with angularjs and $sce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highlighting

Please see the following picture:

[image]

It's good.

Now, please see following picture:

[image]

It's not good for me.

I need to be highlighted first following statement:

statement : `as`

Then the following statement:

statement : `dad`

And they both are highlighted. How to do it?

js code :

```
tableService.highlight = function (text, search) {
                if (!search) {
                    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
                }
                var trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="highlightedText">$&</span>'));

                return trustAsHtml;
            };
```

cshtml code :

```
<td ng-hide="$index == tableService.choiseDeleteRecord ||$index==tableService.choiseUpdateRecord">
                <span ng-bind-html="tableService.highlight(newsCategory.NameFa, pagerService.search)"> {{newsCategory.NameFa}}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="direction-left" ng-hide="$index == tableService.choiseDeleteRecord ||$index==tableService.choiseUpdateRecord">
                <span ng-bind-html="tableService.highlight(newsCategory.NameFa, pagerService.search)"> {{newsCategory.NameEn}}</span>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried and I succeeded. But my code might not be optimal.

Please share if you have a better way

[image]

js code :

```
  tableService.highlight = function (text, search) {
        if (!search) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        }
        var splitSearch = search.split(' ');
        $.each(splitSearch, function (index, value) {
            text = replaceAll(value, '#####$&~~~~~', text);
        });
        text = replaceAll('#####', '<span class="highlightedText">', text);
        text = replaceAll('~~~~~', '</span>', text);
        var trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        return trustAsHtml;
    };
```